# Ошибка AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Tags: python

Вот такой traceback:

```
 File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\oop_parser\boilerpipe_parser_component.py", line 116, in get_nd_date
    unix_date = date_parsed.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')  # < Конвертируем дату в формат datetime
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Код:

```
unix_date = date_parsed.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Вообще, в переменную `unix_date`должно попадать только `class 'datetime.datetime'`, но, судя по ошибке, попадает строка. Я это проверил - так и оказалось, и, в следствии чего, появляется ошибка.

На данный момент на ум пришла проверка на тип данных. То есть как-то так:

```
if type(date_parsed) == datetime.datetime: 
   unix_date = date_parsed.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Какое еще может быть решение этой проблемы?

UPD:Полный код моего метода:

```
@staticmethod
    def get_nd_date(date_parsed):
        """Получение UNIX даты."""
        Try:
            unix_date = date_parsed.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')  # < Конвертируем дату в формат datetime
            nd_date = time.mktime(time.strptime(unix_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))  # < Конвертированную дату  конвертируем в формат UNIX.
            return nd_date
        except AttributeError:
            return ""
```

Comment: Какая у вас цель? Вы хотите конвертировать объект типа `datetime` в UNIX epoch?

Comment: @MaxU, все верно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция для получения UNIX timestamp (AKA `UNIX epoch` - число секунд от начала эпохи - `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`) из строки или из объекта типа `datetime.datetime`:

```
from datetime import datetime as DT

def to_unix_epoch(x, fmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"):
    if isinstance(x, str):
        try:
            return DT.strptime(x, fmt).timestamp()
        except (ValueError, AttributeError):
            return None
    elif isinstance(x, DT):
        try:
            return x.timestamp()
        except (ValueError, AttributeError):
            return None
    return None
```

---

Тесты:

```
In [131]: print(to_unix_epoch(DT.now()))
1571761290.506701

In [132]: print(to_unix_epoch("2019-01-01 12:13:14"))
1546341194.0

In [133]: print(to_unix_epoch(""))
None

In [134]: print(to_unix_epoch(None))
None
```

Answer (score 2):

Оберните логику в функцию с `try: ... except:...` блоком:

```
def format_dt(dt, fmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"):
    try:
        return dt.strftime(fmt)
    except AttributeError:
        return ""
```

---

Тесты:

```
In [93]: format_dt(DT.now())
Out[93]: '2019-10-22 16:04:16'

In [94]: format_dt("")
Out[94]: ''

In [95]: format_dt(None)
Out[95]: ''
```

Comment: Не могли бы вы взглянуть на вопрос еще раз ? Я его немного дополнил.

Comment: @MaxU через что вы тестите что у вас так органично идут In and Out?

Comment: @finally, это "prompt" в `iPython` и в `Jupyter`)